# I'm trying to query a database in MVC4, perform calculations, and display in a chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a bit of difficulty finding a clear answer to this one. I'm trying to query an existing database created through MVC4 below is the code used to create it. I'd like to be able to perform calculations on the data and replace the bar chart array with siphoned data in the second block of code. Thanks.

```
public class GradeBook
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CourseNo { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string AssignType { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class GradeBookDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GradeBook> GradeBooks { get; set; }
```

### }

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Grade', 'Midterm', 'Final'],
          ['<50', 1000, 400],
          ['60-69', 1000, 400],
          ['70-79', 1170, 460],
          ['80-89', 660, 1120],
          ['90-100', 1030, 540]
        ]);
```

Comment: Perhaps your difficulty in finding an answer, is because you never actually asked a question.

Comment: I meant in searching, but I am asking now. Any advice?